# XSD and xmllint : replacing xs:sequence with xs:all gives an error

Tags: xsd, xmllint

I want to validate the following XML, without imposing the order of points :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<root>
  <name>Map corners</name>
  <point>NW</point>
  <point>SW</point>
  <point>NE</point>
  <point>SE</point>
</root>
```

My XSD is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="point" type="xs:string" fixed="NW"/>
      <xs:element name="point" type="xs:string" fixed="SW"/>
      <xs:element name="point" type="xs:string" fixed="NE"/>
      <xs:element name="point" type="xs:string" fixed="SE"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

xmllint validates my XML.

But if I replace xs:sequence with xs:all (to release the order constraint : SW may be before NW), it doesn't validate, and I have the following message :

my6.xsd:4: element complexType: Schemas parser error : local complex type: The content model is not determinist.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0, you can't use xsd:any with a repeating element particle. You can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="point" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="NW"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="SW"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="NE"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="SE"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="pk_points">
            <xs:selector xpath="point"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you Petru. Adding a identity constraint is useful to avoid e.g. NW,NW,NW,SE. It means: "this (.) "point" must be unique" (using xs:key and xs:unique are nearly the same). See also : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_02.htm